# oracle find out date/time of grant

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-grant, privilege

I am using oracle 11g and need to find out date and time of a specific grant.
Is there any way to find out WHEN (date & time) a privilege was granted?
dba_tab_privs has no date column, nor has sys.objauth$...

even if there is no way, please answer if you can provide an oracle document saying so.
I did not find anything and I am searching for 3hrs now.

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe some kind of flashback query
SELECT *
FROM sys.objauth$  VERSIONS BETWEEN TIMESTAMP
      TO_TIMESTAMP('2008-12-18 14:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-24 17:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: Documenting things you can't do would take forever so it's unlikely to be stated anywhere. [You can audit this activity](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4007.htm); but if you're trying to find a grant that's already been made, you aren't already auditing, and it wasn't done within your flashback query window, then... I think you're out of luck as it apparently isn't stored in the data dictionary itself.

Comment: Can you assume that the last DDL that was done to an object was the `GRANT` you are interested in?  If so, you could use the `last_ddl_time` from `dba_objects`.  Generally, I'd agree with @AlexPoole that you would want to enable auditing if you want to track those sorts of things.

Comment: @maksim: unfortunately there is no snapshot (ora-08180)

Comment: @alex: the db admins do no audit (at least not an this level) and yes - they do have some **DDL** triggers but the grant in question was not recorded or they missed it in a way (could have been some years ago)

Comment: @justin: no I cant assume this, the object is some years old and we had several dozen of installations since - all with hundreds of DDLstatements.

Comment: In this particular case we had another installation on a parallel db and this grant was missing. Could not find the grant in the installation scripts so I wanted to know when the privilege was granted. Then I would have been able to check the installations on this particular date. Search is quite tedious since all the installations are archived.  Anyway: thanks to all of you. Meanwhile the priv was granted and I will just add the grant to the next installation script.